# How can I optimize my Google Apps Script so that it doesn't exceed the maximum timeout?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to keep my script from exceeding the maximum execution time, but I'm not sure how to optimize my code.  The part that really hangs is when the file is an APR.  It has to unzip 69 files, convert them to Google docs format, and then overwrite the existing tabs on a Google Sheet.  Thank you!

```
//version 1_20200306

function doGet(e) {
  try {
    var rn = e.parameter.responseNumber;  // takes the response number as a parameter
    rn = Number(rn);  // sets the response number into a variable
    rn = rn + 1;  // increments the response number by 1 to designate the row number

    // begins processing the report form entry
    var reportStatus = processReportForm(rn);

    // if a good status is returned then the script redirects to the success page
    if (reportStatus == "good") {
      var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(reportStatus);
      return output;
    }

  }
  catch(err) {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('failure');
    return output;
  }
};

// gets the most recent file added to the folder
function getLatestFileId(recentFileFolder){

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(recentFileFolder);
  var files = folder.next().getFiles();
  var lastFileId = files.next().getId();

  return lastFileId.toString();

};

// checks to see if demo report code is present
function demoCheckReportCode(rcCheck,rType) {

  if(rcCheck == 'demo' && rType == 'APR') {
    var rcDemoCheckName = '1vH4SidDb6QctTdBtvIUxjpE3RRmZPMo8_fQcNUJqWV0';
  } else if (rcCheck == "demo" && rType == 'SysPM') {
    var rcDemoCheckName = '1D2QJkM0odQBQia9Q2qHGwC_iKHidfvfbQv1xDR6yygk';
  } else if (rcCheck == "demo" && rType == 'SysPM Resubmitted') {
    var rcDemoCheckName = '1D2QJkM0odQBQia9Q2qHGwC_iKHidfvfbQv1xDR6yygk';
  }else if (rcCheck == "demo" && rType == 'CSV') {
    var rcDemoCheckName = '1Wqi6qykTMlMCaoDF1JfE1bOk0H_SykydtCnC2jFoTgI';
  } else {
    var rcDemoCheckName = rcCheck;
  }
  return rcDemoCheckName;
};

// checks to see if report code is demo and returns the folder ID to use
function demoCheckFolderId(fIdCheck) {

  if (fIdCheck == '1vH4SidDb6QctTdBtvIUxjpE3RRmZPMo8_fQcNUJqWV0' ||
      fIdCheck == '1D2QJkM0odQBQia9Q2qHGwC_iKHidfvfbQv1xDR6yygk' ||
      fIdCheck == '1Wqi6qykTMlMCaoDF1JfE1bOk0H_SykydtCnC2jFoTgI') {
    var rcDemoCheckId = '1b-1Ll2O1ZsDztzwoGUnNiPbAVq5-bHXa';
  } else {
    var rcDemoCheckId = getFolderByName(fIdCheck);
  }
  return rcDemoCheckId;
};

function processReportForm(rNumber) {

  var rsId = '11NR47rtjTtdYDK7ZmXDZ38VCC9xRBsiwrixNXfqbjOk'; // ID of Report Submission Form
  var rs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(rsId)
  var sheet = rs.getSheets()[0];
  var rowNumber = rNumber;
  var contactName = sheet.getRange('E' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var reportFileName = sheet.getRange('F' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var dashboardName = sheet.getRange('G' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var reportCode = sheet.getRange('H' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange('I' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var info = sheet.getRange('M' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var type = sheet.getRange('K' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var period = sheet.getRange('L' + rowNumber).getValue();
  var dataSheetName = 'DATA';

  // checks to see if demo report is being used
  reportCode = demoCheckReportCode(reportCode,type);

  // checks to see if folder has files in it
  var etlStatus = checkFolder(reportCode);

  // returns status of etl
  if (etlStatus == reportCode) {
    return etlStatus;
  }

  // takes input form info and adds it to data sheet
  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById(reportCode)
  var dataSheet = ds.getSheets()[0];

  if(type == 'SysPM') {
    dataSheet.getRange('B8').setValue('NO');
  } else if(type == 'SysPM Resubmitted') {
    dataSheet.getRange('B8').setValue('YES');
  }

  // processes uploaded data
  importData(type,reportCode,reportFileName,dataSheetName);

  dataSheet.getRange('B2').setValue(dashboardName);
  dataSheet.getRange('B3').setValue(period);
  dataSheet.getRange('B4').setValue(info);

  // returns etl status
  return etlStatus;
};

function importData(tc,rc,rfn,dsn) {

  // demo report check folder ID
  var folderId = demoCheckFolderId(rc);

  var spreadsheet = rc; // spreadsheet where data goes
  var reportName = rfn; // report file name

  // checks report type
  if(tc == 'APR') {

    // unzip report with csv files and delete report file
    unZipItAPR(folderId,reportName);

    var vFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); // gets folder ID
    var vFiles = vFolder.getFiles(); // populates with a list of files in the folder

    // gets the names of the files in the folder
    while (vFiles.hasNext()) {
      var file = vFiles.next();
      var csvName = file.getName();
      if (csvName != 'Q4a.csv' 
      && csvName != 'Q6e.csv'
      && csvName != 'Q6f.csv'
      && csvName != 'Q7b.csv'
      && csvName != 'Q8b.csv'
      && csvName != 'Q9a.csv'
      && csvName != 'Q9b.csv') {

        // imports csv files into spreadsheet
        importFile(file.getName(),folderId,spreadsheet);
      }
    }

    // converts csv files to Google Sheets format
    convert(folderId);

    var csvFiles = vFolder.getFiles();
      // copies files into data folder
      while (csvFiles.hasNext()) {
        var file = csvFiles.next();
        var Q5aSheetName = file.getName();

        var csvSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
        var Q5aSheet = csvSheet.getSheets()[0];
        var testValue1 = Q5aSheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
        var testValue2 = Q5aSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();

        if (testValue1 == '' && testValue2 == '') {
          Q5aSheet.deleteRow(1);
        }

        // clones the report sheets to the data sheet
        cloneGoogleSheet(file.getId(),spreadsheet,Q5aSheetName,Q5aSheetName);
      }

    // checks report type
  } else if(tc == 'SysPM' || tc == 'SysPM Resubmitted') {

    // converts xls to google sheets format
    var sourceFileId = convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(folderId,reportName);
    if(tc == 'SysPM') {
      var sourceSheetNameOne = 'SysPMSummary2016_1';
      var destSheetNameOne = 'SysPMSummary2016_1';
    } else if(tc == 'SysPM Resubmitted') {
      var sourceSheetNameOne = 'SysPMSummary2016Rev';
      var destSheetNameOne = 'SysPMSummary2016Rev';
    }
    var sourceSheetNameTwo = 'SysPMSummary';
    var destSheetNameTwo = 'SysPMSummary';

    // clones the report sheets to the data sheet
    cloneGoogleSheet(sourceFileId,spreadsheet,sourceSheetNameOne,destSheetNameOne);
    cloneGoogleSheet(sourceFileId,spreadsheet,sourceSheetNameTwo,destSheetNameTwo);
  } else if(tc == 'CSV') {

    // unzip report with csv files and delete report file
    unZipItCSV(folderId,reportName);

    // converts csv files to Google Sheets format
    convert(folderId);

    var vFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); // gets folder ID
    var vFiles = vFolder.getFiles(); // populates with a list of files in the folder
    var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(rc);

    var parentFold = thisFile.getParents(); // Get all parents - normally just one parent
    var targetFolder = parentFold.next(); // Get the first parent folder
    var targetFolderFiles = targetFolder.getFiles(); // populates with a list of files in the folder
    var dateFile = DriveApp.getFileById('1jj97O7RxPQzV3kpqUlYwI5HIQS6BcSsV-w0HAiJUTio'); //Master Dates file id

    // makes a copy of the Master Dates file into the upload folder
    dateFile.makeCopy(vFolder).setName(dateFile.getName());

    // copies files into data folder
    while (vFiles.hasNext()) {
      var file = vFiles.next();
      if (file.getName() == 'Client'||
          file.getName() == 'Enrollment'||
          file.getName() == 'Exit'||
          file.getName() == 'HealthAndDV'||
          file.getName() == 'Master Dates'||
          file.getName() == 'Project') {

          // removes unnecessary columns
          deleteColumns(file.getId(),file.getName());

          // gets current file/sheet name
          var sheetName = file.getName();

          // clones the report sheets to the data sheet
          cloneGoogleSheet(file.getId(),spreadsheet,sheetName,sheetName);
      }
    }
  }
};

// unzips APR zip file
function unZipItAPR(fo,na) {
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fo); // folder with zipped report
  var theFile = theFolder.getFilesByName(na); // gets the contents of the zip file
  var fileBlob = theFile.next().getBlob(); // stores the files for processing
  fileBlob.setContentType("application/zip"); //sets the correct file type for the zip file
  var unZippedFiles = Utilities.unzip(fileBlob);

  // unzips the files into the folder
  for (var i in unZippedFiles) {
  if (unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q4a.csv' 
      && unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q6e.csv'
      && unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q6f.csv'
      && unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q7b.csv'
      && unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q8b.csv'
      && unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q9a.csv'
      && unZippedFiles[i].getName() != 'Q9b.csv') {
    var newDriveFile = DriveApp.createFile(unZippedFiles[i]);
    var zipFile = newDriveFile.getId();
    theFolder.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(zipFile));
    DriveApp.removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(zipFile));
    }
  }
  // removes file after it has been unzipped
  DriveApp.getFilesByName(na).next().setTrashed(true);
};

// unzips CSV zip file
function unZipItCSV(fo,na) {
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fo); // folder with zipped report
  var theFile = theFolder.getFilesByName(na); // gets the contents of the zip file
  var fileBlob = theFile.next().getBlob(); // stores the files for processing
  fileBlob.setContentType("application/zip"); // sets the correct file type for the zip file
  var unZippedFiles = Utilities.unzip(fileBlob);

  // unzips the files into the folder
  for (var i in unZippedFiles) {
  var csvZipName = unZippedFiles[i].getName();
  if (csvZipName == 'Client.csv'
      || csvZipName == 'Enrollment.csv'
      || csvZipName == 'Exit.csv'
      || csvZipName == 'HealthAndDV.csv'
      || csvZipName == 'Project.csv') {
    var newDriveFile = DriveApp.createFile(unZippedFiles[i]);
    var zipFile = newDriveFile.getId();
    theFolder.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(zipFile));
    DriveApp.removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(zipFile));
    }
  }
  // removes file after it has been unzipped
  DriveApp.getFilesByName(na).next().setTrashed(true);
};

// imports files into data spreadsheet
function importFile(fiName,foId,spId) {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById(foId); // folder where csv files are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName(fiName); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spId); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data

  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if csv file exists in the folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function

    // removes the extension from file name
    var fiNameShort = fiName.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(fiNameShort);

    // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'DATA' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }

    // trashes the csv file
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
  }
};

// http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm
// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
  // check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to COMMA.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );

  // create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // we found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // we found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
};

// function that returns folder ID based on folder name
function getFolderByName(folderName) {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  var folderID = null;
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folderID = folders.next().getId();
    }
  return folderID;
};

// checks the status of the folder to make sure there aren't any files already in it
function checkFolder(cc) {
  var ccStatus = cc;

  // checks if demo report is being used
  var cFolderId = demoCheckFolderId(ccStatus);

  var cFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(cFolderId);
  var recentFileId = getLatestFileId(cFolder);
  var cFiles = cFolder.getFiles();

  // cleans up any previously leftover files leaving the current report file alone
  while (cFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = cFiles.next();
    if (file.getId() != recentFileId) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
    }
  }

  ccStatus = 'good';
  return ccStatus;
};

// converts xls file to google sheet
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(foId,fiNa) {

  fiNa = fiNa || "microsoft-excel.xls";

  var folderId = foId;
  var convertFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var excelFile = convertFolder.getFiles().next();
  var fileId = excelFile.getId();
  var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: excelFile.getName().replace(/.xls?/, ""),
    parents: [{ id: folderId }],
    key: fileId
  };
  var createFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {
    convert: true
  });
  Drive.Files.remove(excelFile.getId());
  return createFile.id;

};

// copy data from Google Sheet A to Google Sheet B
// Credit: @chrislkeller

function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA,ssB,ssName,sdName) {

  // source doc
  var ssDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssA);

  // source sheet
  var sSheet = ssDoc.getSheetByName(ssName);

  // get full range of data
  var SRange = sSheet.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssB);

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName(sdName);

  // clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};

// converts files in folder to Google format
function convert(convertFolder) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(convertFolder);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
  }
};

// deletes unused columns in csv to save space
function deleteColumns(csvSheetId, csvSheetName) {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(csvSheetId)
  var csName = csvSheetName;
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(csName), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  var header = spreadsheet.getRange('1:1');
  var deleteValues = (header.getValues());
  var counter = 1;
  for (i=0; i<deleteValues[0].length; i++) {
    if
      (
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'FirstName' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'MiddleName' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LastName' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SSN' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'NameSuffix' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'NameDataQuality' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SSNDataQuality' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DOBDataQuality' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'YearEnteredService' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'YearSeparated' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'WorldWarII' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'KoreanWar' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'VietnamWar' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DesertStorm' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AfghanistanOEF' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'IraqOIF' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'IraqOND' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'OtherTheater' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'MilitaryBranch' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DischargeStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateCreated' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateUpdated' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'UserID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateDeleted' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ExportID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'OrganizationID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ProjectName' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'OperatingStartDate' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'OperatingEndDate' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ContinuumProject' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HousingType' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ResidentialAffiliation' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'TrackingMethod' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HMISParticipatingProject' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'TargetPopulation' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PITCount' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateCreated' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateUpdated' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'UserID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateDeleted' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HealthAndDVID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'InformationDate' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'WhenOccurred' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CurrentlyFleeing' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'GeneralHealthStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DentalHealthStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'MentalHealthStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PregnancyStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DueDate' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DataCollectionStage' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ExitID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'OtherDestination' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HousingAssessment' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SubsidyInformation' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ProjectCompletionStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'EarlyExitReason' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ExchangeForSex' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ExchangeForSexPastThreeMonths' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CountOfExchangeForSex' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ExchangeForSexPastThreeMonths' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CountOfExchangeForSex' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AskedOrForcedToExchangeForSex' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AskedOrForcedToExchangeForSexPastThreeMonths' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'WorkPlaceViolenceThreats' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'WorkPlacePromiseDifference' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CoercedToContinueWork' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LaborExploitPastThreeMonths' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CounselingReceived' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'IndividualCounseling' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'FamilyCounseling' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'GroupCounseling' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SessionCountAtExit' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PostExitCounselingPlan' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SessionsInPlan' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DestinationSafeClient' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DestinationSafeWorker' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PosAdultConnections' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PosPeerConnections' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PosCommunityConnections' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AftercareDate' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AftercareProvided' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'EmailSocialMedia' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'Telephone' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'InPersonIndividual' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'InPersonGroup' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CMExitReason' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HouseholdID' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LOSUnderThreshold' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateToStreetESSH' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'TimesHomelessPastThreeYears' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'MonthsHomelessPastThreeYears' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateOfEngagement' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'MoveInDate' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateOfPATHStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ClientEnrolledInPATH' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ReasonNotEnrolled' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'WorstHousingSituation' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PercentAMI' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LastPermanentStreet' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LastPermanentCity' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LastPermanentState' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LastPermanentZIP' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AddressDataQuality' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DateOfBCPStatus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'EligibleForRHY' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ReasonNoServices' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'RunawayYouth' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SexualOrientation' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SexualOrientationOther' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'FormerWardChildWelfare' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ChildWelfareYears' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ChildWelfareMonths' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'FormerWardJuvenileJustice' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'JuvenileJusticeYears' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'JuvenileJusticeMonths' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'UnemploymentFam' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'MentalHealthIssuesFam' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'PhysicalDisabilityFam' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AlcoholDrugAbuseFam' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'InsufficientIncome' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'IncarceratedParent' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ReferralSource' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CountOutreachReferralApproaches' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'UrgentReferral' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'TimeToHousingLoss' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ZeroIncome' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'AnnualPercentAMI' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'FinancialChange' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HouseholdChange' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'EvictionHistory' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SubsidyAtRisk' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'LiteralHomelessHistory' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DisabledHoH' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'CriminalRecord' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SexOffender' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'DependentUnder6' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'SingleParent' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HH5Plus' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'IraqAfghanistan' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'FemVet' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'HPScreeningScore' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'VAMCStation' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'ThresholdScore' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == ''
         )
          {
            spreadsheet.deleteColumn(counter); }
    else {
      counter = counter + 1;
    }
  }
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(csName), false);
};
```

Comment: Your code certainly performs a heavy workload which is time consuming. Should you not be able to optimize it enough to avoid timeout - you can run it in batches. The [continuation token](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.html#getcontinuationtoken) allows you to resume your file iteration where it stopped during the last execution.

Comment: Consider posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Posted to codereview.stackexchange.com.